# PDO param is reading as a string and not an int

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to pass a GET var into the query to set the OFFSET.

```
try {

  $sql_offset =  isset($_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

  $main_query = "SELECT * FROM Orders
                LIMIT 150 OFFSET :offset";

  $result = $db->prepare($main_query);
  $result->bindParam(':offset', $sql_offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $result->execute();

} catch (Exception $e) {

  $error = $e->getMessage();
  echo "<h2>".$error."</h2>";
  die();

}
```

The query fails and the error message received is:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''450'' at line 2

Note: If I place 450 directly into the query it works fine.
It seems to me that the problem is that it is reading the param as a string '450' and not an int 450. I tried solving that with the `PDO::PARAM_INT` - didn't help. 
I parsed the value with `(int)$sql_offset` and `int_val($sql_offset)` and didn't help. Meaning, I was still receiving the same error message.

Question: am I right? Is the problem that it is seeing as a string? If so, how can I fix?
Or is there a different problem here?

Comment: Try this `$main_query = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT :offset, 150";`

Comment: Try `$result->bindValue(':offset', (int) $sql_offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: Are you using native or emulated prepared statements?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Thanks! that worked. If you want to you can post the answer and I'll accept it. :-)

Comment: No. Next time please use the search on StackOverflow! Álvarao González marked this question as duplicate. I got the solution also from this duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @SebastianBrosch For sure I did a search before I posted and must have missed this or thought it didn't apply. As an aside - the others title was very specific in the wording with "bindValue" and "LIMIT" while I was looking for bindParam and OFFSET. Anyway, no worries and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse value in `int` then check:

```
$sql_offset =  (int)(isset($_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0);
```